# Should we rewrite the XSL in CDuce?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd, xslt-1.0

We currently have a huge XSLT transformation that takes 20-30 minutes to process.  We need to improve the performance and we are considering [CDuce](http://www.cduce.org/).  CDuce looks promising.  What is a good approach to doing this?  Do we have to rewrite the entire xsl logic in CDuce?

Comment: You should probably understand why your XSL takes so long.

If the input file is "huge" it may take that long in any language.

The XSL stylesheet could be poorly written, or may be structured in a way that results in inefficient processing. Maybe a different XSLT engine would perform better.

If you undertake a large rewrite without understanding the inefficiencies of the existing system you may end up with something that is no faster.

Comment: Post some sample input and enough of the stylesheet so that we can see the overall approach it uses.

Comment: In general, the only good approach to performance issues is:  measure.  Without careful measurement to find the performance bottlenecks, all conjectures about what is causing the program to be slow are likely to be worthless, or worse than worthless (because they tempt you to waste time on irrelevant changes).  In general, it will be simpler to try a transform with multiple XSLT processors, to measure it to find hotspots, to experiment with reformulating the hotspots, and to consult the vendor than to translate a "huge" program to another language.

Comment: Agree 100% with the comments above. You can justify small amounts of time spent on experimental changes to your code if they help you understand the performance characteristics better, but a major rewrite to fix a problem you don't understand is likely to be a gross waste of effort.

Comment: Hi Jim, the input file is a 9MB word xml file with a lot of stylesheet info.  Thank you for the comments, and I do agree with you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite it in another language but there may be easier options, it depends how efficient that XSLT 1 code is. If it uses `//` a lot then it is not uncommon to get orders of magnitude speed improvement by rewriting it not to use `//` and to use keys or other constructs instead. Also of course switching to a newer more highly optimised XSLT engine wouldn't hurt. (Your question is tagged xslt 1 but an XSLT2 engine would be able to run it with no or little change)

Comment: I followed your advise, and we are seeing notable improvements by refactoring several of the // selects.  Thank you.