# How to refactor this xslt that has //?

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt, xpath

I am refactoring an xslt for word xml to improve performance as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488207/should-we-rewrite-the-xsl-in-cduce).  I am relatively new to xslt.  Why are the following statements not equivalent?

**Form1**

```
<xsl:value-of select="//w:style[@w:styleId = $styleName][ancestor::pkg:part/@pkg:name='/word/styles.xml']"/>
```

**Form2**

```
<xsl:value-of select="/pkg:package/pkg:part[@pkg:name='/word/styles.xml']/child::w:style[@w:styleId = $styleName]" />
```

Note that pkg:package is the root and pkg:part are direct children.

Form1 states that get the w:style element with the attribute equaling `$styleName`, whose ancestors are `pkg:part` with attribute `@pkg:name='/word/styles.xml'`.

Form 2 states that get the w:style elements with the attributes equaling `$styleName` who are children of `pkg:package/pkg:par@pkg:name='/word/styles.xml'`

The actual statement I am trying to rewrite is this one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//w:style[@w:styleId = $styleName][ancestor::pkg:part/@pkg:name='/word/styles.xml']/w:pPr/w:numPr/w:numId/@w:val"/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second XPath is on the right track, but it would only match `w:styles` that are direct children of `pkg:part` (the `child::` axis is redundant here), which I don't think they are.  This should work:

```
/pkg:package/pkg:part[@pkg:name='/word/styles.xml']//w:style[@w:styleId = $styleName]
```

and I think this is an improvement over the original XPath, but it still has a `//` in it. My knowledge of wordprocessingML is not very extensive, but is it the case that all `<w:style>`s are the children of `<w:styles>` elements, which are all children of a `<pkg:xmlData>` element?  If so, this should work (split across 2 lines for readability):

```
/pkg:package/pkg:part[@pkg:name='/word/styles.xml']
                               /pkg:xmlData/w:styles/w:style[@w:styleId = $styleName]
```

One other possibility for improving performance is to use a key.  In your XSLT, you would define a key like this:

```
<xsl:key name="kStyle" match="w:style" use="@w:styleId" />
```

And then you would access the style you want like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('kStyle', $styleName)
                               [ancestor::pkg:part/@pkg:name = '/word/styles.xml']
                               /w:pPr/w:numPr/w:numId/@w:val" />
```

Key lookups are generally very efficient, so this second option may be the better one in terms of performance.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  Your first suggestion worked right away.  Will try out your second suggestion as well.  Thank you again.

Comment: Your second suggestion works for the limited cases I tried as well.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume that starting an expression with "//" is always bad. This used to be true in the early days, and it may still be true of processors that haven't advanced much since the early days, but some processors including modern versions of Saxon process "//" very efficiently. If you're going to make such changes, make sure you make measurements that show the changes to be effective. For this kind of expression, using a key is much more likely to have a positive effect - though some processors will even do that for you automatically.

Comment: To amplify this, I just saw this tweet: Markus Wiedenmaier @MWiedenmaier 10h xml 3MB with a lot of //element calls in xslt 1.0: saxon und msxsl ~3sek xalanj ~6min xalanc 10min+